# Angular 4 Property does not exist on type Object on build

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building a project using Angular, I started the project using angular-cli and when I try to run `ng build --prod` i keep getting this error:

> Property 'description' does not exist on type Object

The code generating this error is the following:

```
export class AppComponent {
    product: Object = {};

    constructor(
        private store: StoreService,
        private request: RequestService,
    ) {
        this.product = this.request.getProduct(_id);
    }
}

<p>{{product.description}}</p>
```

I was reading some content about this and the error is because I'm using type definition to define product as Object, but I'm not passing any property definition.

I know I could define an Interface, like I do with arrays, but I wasn't able to do it. I don't know if I'm defining it wrong, this is how I tried:

```
export interface ProductInterface {
    id: Number;
    description: String;
    title: String;
}

product: Object<ProductInterface> = {};
```

But it also gives me errors. What do I need to do to avoid this?

Comment: The type of `product` should be `ProductInterface`, not `Object<ProductInterface>`.

Comment: who is getProduct

Comment: Try this: ng build --prod --aot false

Comment: Or this one maybe better: ng build --prod --aot false --build-optimizer false

Comment: use `any` ie `product: any;`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For your first example. In your html, you are saying product has the property description (which it does not on type Object)

In your second example. You are initially defining product as an empty object

```
product: ProductInterface = {};
```

Which is missing the required fields of the interface. So you can remove the initialization, leaving

```
product: ProductInterface;
```

Also as others have noted, you do not need the Object<> syntax

Comment: I have a dynamic form and don't know any form control while compilation, at compilation time I get  for ex:`Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.`  any solutions for this type of forms?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya If there are unknown properties in your object you can add dynamic properties `product: {[key: string]: string}` This will allow you to assign whatever key (type string) to the object with a value (type string). This is called an index signature (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html)

Comment: Thank you very much man, you saved many lives, that index structure is working like a charm

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya glad I could help!

Answer (score 9):

From my case..

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.product = this.request.getProduct(_id); // who is _id
}
```

> Just adding **data:any** at subscription works fine.

```
this.request.getProduct(_id).subscribe((data: any) => {
   this.product=data;
});
```

This would helpful while the response data having more key, value pairs. (So Its hard/Time consuming to create Interface.)

But always the best practise is to use Interfaces ;)

Answer (score 8):

If the property is dynamic (not known at compile time), you can use

```
someObject['someProperty']
```

instead of

```
someObject.someProperty
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything in Angular v16

Answer (score 5):

First of all I would simply use `product: ProductInterface;` and you don't even have to initialize it.

Then, probably this will fix your error `{{ product?. description }}`

Comment: What does it mean to use `?` ?

Comment: @celsomtrindade that is the safe navigation operator (I believe its called elvis operator in other languages) http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-pipe-operator-and-safe-navigation-operator-example . Basically angular won't look for the description field until product is defined. Without it you may get an cannot read property description of undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the request in OnInit method, your controller that implements OnInit interface and define a new method

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.product = this.request.getProduct(_id); // who is _id
}
```

Assuming that getProduct() is http request that return a observable

```
this.request.getProduct(_id).subscribe((data) => {
   this.product=data;
});
```

Comment: that's not the point, I just removed the unecessary code and forgot this part. The request function is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to use `any` rather than `Object` when data is requested from server, because we don't know what will be returned from server. So you don't need to **typecheck** ie:

```
export class AppComponent {
    product: any;

    constructor(
        private store: StoreService,
        private request: RequestService,
    ) {
        this.product = this.request.getProduct(_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may be true at the time it was written, TypeScript has since included `unknown` to serve this very purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you use command `ng serve` and build success.

May,you have the trouble with [build configuration](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements)

maybe you need to modify the `className.prod.ts` like `className.ts`

my another answer has more detail:

[Angular - How to fix 'property does not exist on type' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67700519/7960551)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 16 none of the other solutions worked.

Luckily, the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck) is clear about this: you can use `$any(...)`:

```
{{ $any(product).unknownProperty }}
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case it worked after set my properties as **public**

So, just change this

```
export interface ProductInterface {
    id: Number;
    description: String;
    title: String;
}
```

to this

```
export interface ProductInterface {
    public id: Number;
    public description: String;
    public title: String;
}
```