# Property 'getmobileList' does not exist on type 'MobileService'. Angular 4

Tags: angular, service, angular-providers

[image: After taking out code from NgoninIt]I am working on Angular 4.

So  created a custom service and i Imported into providers of  `app.module.ts`
and i created an interface

When i am trying retrieve data from that service

i am getting an error

> ERROR in D:/Personal/My Practice/MOBILEKART/src/app/mobiles/mobiles.component.ts (61,40): Property 'getmobileList' does not exist on type 'MobileService'.

can anyone advise what is happening..

and i tried [to Keep public for my properties as suggested in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811434/angular-4-property-does-not-exist-on-type-object-on-build)

--Thanks in Advance.

`mobile Component.ts`

```
import {      Component,      OnInit    } from '@angular/core';
import {      mobile    } from './mobile';
import {      MobileService    } from './mobile_service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mobiles',
  templateUrl: './mobiles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mobiles.component.css']
})
export class MobilesComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'MOBILE CART';
  image = 'assets/images/';
  click = false;
  showImages = true;
  refineMobile = ' ';
  shop = 'assets/images/Cart.jpg';
  errorMessage: string;
  mobiles: mobile[] = [];
  // filter by name
    filterMobiles: mobile[];
    _listFilter: string;

    // constructor
    constructor(private _mobileservice: MobileService) {
      this.filterMobiles = this.mobiles;
      this.listFilter = '';
    }

  displayImages(): void {
    this.showImages == true ?
      (this.showImages = false) :
      (this.showImages = true);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('oninit of angular is initialised');
    // retrieving product with custom service..
    this.mobiles = this._mobileservice.getmobileList();
    this.filterMobiles = this.mobiles;

    get listFilter() {
      return this._listFilter;
    }
    set listFilter(value) {
      this._listFilter = value;
      this.filterMobiles = this.listFilter ?
        this.performFilter(this.listFilter) :
        this.mobiles;
    }
    performFilter(filterBy: string): mobile[] {
      filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
      return this.mobiles.filter(
        (mobile: mobile) =>
        mobile.mobile_name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1
      );
    }
  }
```

`mobile.ts`

```
  export interface mobile {
    imageUrl: string;
    mobile_name: string;
    mobile_price: number;
    mobile_code: string;
    release_date: string;
    rating: number;
 }
```

`mobile_service_ts`

```
    import {          mobile        } from './mobile';
    import {          Injectable        } from '@angular/core';        
    import {          HttpClient,          HttpErrorResponse        } from '@angular/common/http';
    import {          Observable        } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

    @Injectable()
    export class MobileService {
      mobileList: mobile[];
      constructor() {}

      // retriving product with custom service..

      getmobileList(): mobile[] {
        this.mobileList = [{
            //imageUrl: 'assets/download.jpg',
            imageUrl: 'download.jpg',
            mobile_name: 'Lenovo',
            mobile_price: 10000,
            mobile_code: 'K3',
            release_date: 'mar 19,2016',
            rating: 4
          },
          {
            //imageUrl: 'assets/download (1).jpg',
            imageUrl: 'download (1).jpg',
            mobile_name: 'samsung',
            mobile_price: 7000,
            mobile_code: 'ON-5',
            release_date: 'nov 18,2017',
            rating: 3
          },
          {
            // imageUrl: "assets/nokia.jpeg"
            imageUrl: 'nokia.jpeg',
            mobile_name: 'Nokia',
            mobile_price: 15000,
            mobile_code: '7',
            release_date: 'oct 24, 2017',
            rating: 4,
          },
          {
            // imageUrl: "assets/iphone.jpeg"
            imageUrl: "iphone.jpeg",
            mobile_name: 'Iphone',
            mobile_price: 70000,
            mobile_code: '7s',
            release_date: 'oct 13 2016',
            rating: 3.5,
          }
        ];
        return this.mobileList;
      }
    }
```

`app.module.ts`

```
    import {          BrowserModule        } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {          NgModule        } from '@angular/core';
    import {          FormsModule        } from '@angular/forms';
    import {          HttpClientModule        } from '@angular/common/http';
    import {          RouterModule        } from '@angular/router';

    import {          AppComponent        } from './app.component';
    import {          MobilesComponent        } from  ./mobiles/mobiles.component';
    import {          MobileService        } from ./mobiles/mobile_service';



    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ...
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
          ...
        ])
      ],
      providers: [MobileService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
    /*platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);*/
```

Comment: Can you please move the code outside `ngOnInit()` and then try debugger to see if you have access to `getmobileList()` inside component. If you cant see `getmobileList()` please share the screenshot while debugging

Comment: i have kept image @ShashankVivek

Comment: Are you able to access `mobileList` of `MobileService` ?

Answer (score 0):

i Got the answer
In  `mobile Component.ts`

I have added interface instead of Service in the above code..
So i replaced it with service in constructor

```
constructor(private _mobileservice: MobileService) {
  this.filterMobiles = this.mobiles;
  this.listFilter = '';
}
```